# Can I split a large file into multiple files each containing x amount of columns (in bash)?

Tags: bash, awk, split, cut

I have a file with 500,000 columns and I would like to split this file into 50 files containing 10,000 columns each. Ideally, a command like `split` that cuts by columns, rather than lines.

I have tried using `cut`:

```
cut -d ' ' -f1-10000 file.txt
```

However, this is impractical to repeat 50 times and as the file is so big, it takes a lot of time and so I would like to only have to read the file once.

I have also tried `awk`, but I can only seem to split the file into single columns:

```
awk -F '[\t;]' '{for(i=1; i<=NF; $((i++))) print $i >> "column" i ".txt"}' file.txt
```

Any ideas would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts, could you please also do mention samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: please update the question to confirm the field/column delimiter; the sample `sed` command is using a space as a delimiter while the `awk` code is using a dual delimiter of tab *or* semicolon ... which is it?  could you also update the question to include your `awk` version (`awk --version`)?

Comment: a sample of your data file would be helpful, eg, the first 5 lines consisting of the first 10 columns

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this in awk but it seems to be quite slow:

```
awk '
    {
        for( i=c=1; i<=50; i++ ){
            o = $(c++)
            for( n=1; n<10000; n++ ) o = o OFS $(c++)
            print o > "part" i ".txt"
        }
    }
' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Play with this

```
awk -v le="10000" '{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i+=le){
      col=""
      max=i+le
      file=i"-"max-1".txt"
      for (j=i; j<max; j++){
        col=col $(j) FS
      }
      print col > file
    }
}' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can only seem to split the file into single columns

If you are allowed to use commands other than `awk` and are ok with using tab as separator then you might give a try [`paste`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) command. For example if you have files named `col1.txt`, `col2.txt`, `col3.txt`, `col4.txt`, `col5.txt` each with single column you might do

```
paste col1.txt col2.txt col3.txt col4.txt col5.txt > col1_5.txt
```

to get ensemble of said columns.

> Any ideas would be very much appreciated :)

Change your definition of column. Consider following GNU `AWK` example, let `file.txt` content be

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="---";FPAT="[^[:space:]]+([[:space:]][^[:space:]]+){2}"}{print $1,$2,$3}' file.txt
```

output

```
1 2 3---4 5 6---7 8 9
10 20 30---40 50 60---70 80 90
100 200 300---400 500 600---700 800 900
```

Explanation: for demonstration purposes I set output field separator (`OFS`) to `---`. Then I inform GNU `AWK` that it should consider following to be column: one or more non-whitespace followed by (whitespace followed by one or more non-whitespace) which is repeated twice. This way each column will hold three values (this can be easily adjusted by changing `{2}` to desired value minus 1) and now you *can only seem to split the file into single columns*. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes number of columns is evenly divisible.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -v n="${n}" '                          # pass in bash variable "n" representing number of columns to place in a single file
    { sfx=0                                # initialize file suffix/counter

      for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {              # loop through all columns
          if (i%n == 1) {                  # at beginning of new set of "n" columns ...
             sfx++                         # increment file suffix/counter
             pfx=""                        # initialize printf column delimiter
          }
          printf "%s%s", pfx, $i > "outfile_" sfx ".txt"
          pfx=OFS                          # update printf column delimiter
      }
      for (i=1; i<=sfx; i++)               # at end of input line: loop through list of open files and ...
          print "" > "outfile_" i ".txt"   # append a linefeed at the end of each current output line
    }
' file.txt
```

**NOTES:**

- need confirmation from OP on the field delimiter(s) at which point will need to update the answer accordingly
- OP mentions the creation of 50 files; this answer will hold all 50 files open while processing the file; `GNU awk` should have no problems maintaining 50 open file descriptors but I don't know about other flavors of `awk`

Sample input file:

```
$ cat file.txt
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

With `n=3`:

```
$ head outfile_*.txt
==> outfile_1.txt <==
1 2 3
1 2 3
1 2 3

==> outfile_2.txt <==
4 5 6
4 5 6
4 5 6

==> outfile_3.txt <==
7 8 9
7 8 9
7 8 9

==> outfile_4.txt <==
10
10
10
```

With `n=4`:

```
$ head outfile_*.txt
==> outfile_1.txt <==
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4

==> outfile_2.txt <==
5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8

==> outfile_3.txt <==
9 10
9 10
9 10
```